# i cant send data from android to server by post

Tags: android, eclipse

i cant send data from andorid device to url 
please help me !
this is my class
what is problem of my code ?

```
package com.example.test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

import android.os.AsyncTask;



public class loginserver extends AsyncTask{

    private String Link="";
    private String User="";
    private String Pass="";



    public loginserver(String link,String user,String pass){

        Link=link;
        User=user;
        Pass=pass;
    }



    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Object... arg0) {


        try{

            String data=URLEncoder.encode("username","UTF8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(User,"UTF8");
            data+="&"+URLEncoder.encode("password","UTF8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(Pass,"UTF8");



            URL mylink=new URL(Link);
            URLConnection connect=mylink.openConnection();

            connect.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStreamWriter wr=new OutputStreamWriter(connect.getOutputStream());
            wr.write(data);
            wr.flush();


            BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connect.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();

            String line=null;

            while((line=reader.readLine()) !=null){

                sb.append(line);

            }

            Main.res = sb.toString();




        }catch(Exception e){



        }



        return "";
    }

}
```

and this is my main code
problem in class code or main code?

```
package com.example.test;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.webkit.WebStorage.Origin;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class Main extends Activity {

    public static String res="";
    private EditText usertext,passtext;
    private Button login,register,exit;


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        usertext =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.usertext);
        passtext =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.passtext);


        login =(Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
        exit =(Button) findViewById(R.id.exit);
        register =(Button) findViewById(R.id.register);

        login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {

login(usertext.getText().toString(),passtext.getText().toString());


            }
        });


    }

 private void login (String user,String pass ){

     new loginserver("my address",user,pass ).execute();

     final ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(Main.this);
     pd.setMessage("please wait");
     pd.show();

     final Timer tm = new Timer();
     tm.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask(){
        public void run() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                if(res.equals("")){
                    pd.cancel();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), res, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                    tm.cancel();
                }

            }
        });

        }

     },1, 1000);
 }

}
```

the php code work true - but i cant send data from android device
is ther any body know my mistakes ?

Comment: What does "can't" mean? Are you getting an error? If so, please post it.

Comment: no error - it return empty value - and didnt show any thing ! in php code should return some value - im shure problem from my android code - because php code work true

Comment: i can read file from text in server - but just i cant read value by post method ! like login form o everything like that – @ChrisThompson

Answer (score 0):

at first you have to setup the internet permissions in the manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

It would also be helpful if you check at first if the network is available.

```
private boolean networkIsAvailable(Context con) {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) 
        con.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

After that, you have to work with the HttpClient.
Check this post how to do this:

[Android HTTP-POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22733870/android-http-post)

Comment: internet permison is true  ! network is available ! because i can read file from text in server - but just i cant read value by post method ! like login form o everything like that